# How would I assign a variable to another variable plus a constant

Tags: javascript, variables

What I am looking for is something similar to a get property of C#, but for JS. An example of what I am wanting would look like this:

```
function myObj(a, b){
     this.a = a;
     this.b = b;
     this.c = a + 5;
}
```

Let's say I passed in a 5 and a 3. Then a=5, b=3, and c=10. Which is what I want. Now I want to come down into somewhere else and say

```
obj.a = 10;
```

So now a=10, b=3, and c=10. This is not what I want, I want c=15 to reflect the change in a. I have been working on this for about 40 minutes and am so frustrated that I cannot seem to get this to work the way I would like. I've tried functions, I've tried what is in the example, and I have tried using the get/set features in ES5 (6? idk when they joined the party)

Anyway, help appreciated, something simple and frustrating. I hate working in JS, lord deliver me from this evil ;)

Comment: Please note that many consider this [bad practice](http://michaelrbernste.in/2013/12/10/why-we-need-explicit-state.html) increasing the risk of certain classes of bugs, and hurting the ease of reasoning about the code. Especially in parallel and concurrent scenarios. This is not to say it doesn't have its uses... (as the article shows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I am looking for is something similar to a get property of C#, but for JS.

That would be a get property:

```js
class MyObj {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    get c() {
        return this.a + 5;
    }
}


let obj = new MyObj(5, 3);
console.log(obj.c);
obj.a = 10;
console.log(obj.c);
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been driving me nuts. Now I need to figure out how to use the get property using the function syntax like I used in the example, any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: @JakeGill70: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty on the prototype.

Comment: Alright, getting some errors now. Not great, but it at least means that I am making progress and it is something with my syntax and not my logic that is screwed up. Much easier to solve. Thanks for your help, Ryan :)